# Accent VS figure caption

Tags: floats, captions, accents

I have a small question.

Although the rest of my document displays correctly the accents such as "é" or "à", the captions of my figures make them disappear... Here is my code:

```
% =================================================== Classe du document

\documentclass[10pt,
            twoside,
            a4paper,
            openright,
            ]{book}
% =================================================== géométrie des pages

\usepackage[a4paper,
            width=150mm,
            top=25mm,
            bottom=25mm,
            bindingoffset=0.1cm,
            headheight=65pt,
            %showframe      % afficher les limites du bloc de texte
            ]{geometry}

% =================================================== Packages divers   

\usepackage{lipsum}             %permet de générer du texte de remplissage
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}        % permet d'insérer des fichiers .pdf
\usepackage{microtype}          % réglage fin de la typographie 
\usepackage{graphicx}           % gère l'insertion de figures
\usepackage{booktabs}           % style des tableaux

% =================================================== Gestion des références de figures et tableaux

\usepackage{cleveref}                   % insère fig. ou table
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}      % renommer les références automatiques
\crefname{table}{tableau}{tableaux}     % renommer les références automatiques
\crefname{appendix}{}{}                 % renommer les références automatiques

% =================================================== Gestion de la langue française

\usepackage[french]{babel}      %polyglossia faisait buger la TOC (pas de n°aux parties)

% =================================================== Gestion des polices

\usepackage{fontspec}       % sert à sélectionner les polices facilement

\setmainfont[
BoldFont={GaramondPremrPro-Bd}, 
ItalicFont={GaramondPremrPro-It},
BoldItalicFont={GaramondPremrPro-BdIt}
]{GaramondPremrPro}
\setsansfont[Scale=0.8]{GothamHTF-Book}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{exemple_de_prelevement_OSL.jpg}
\label{Exemple de prélèvement OSL}
\caption{Exemple de prélèvement OSL}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is my log file :

```
    This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)  (format=lualatex 2015.11.21)  2 AUG 2016 22:39
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**These_faleme.tex
(./These_faleme.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count88
\Gm@cntv=\count89
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count90
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
Package: lipsum 2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\c@lips@count=\count91
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
Package: pdfpages 2015/05/11 v0.4x Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count92
\calc@Bcount=\count93
\calc@Adimen=\dimen111
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen112
\calc@Askip=\skip43
\calc@Bskip=\skip44
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count94
\calc@Cskip=\skip45
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2015/04/20 v2.0e eso-pic (RN)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
\Gread@gobject=\count95
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 94.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen113
\Gin@req@width=\dimen114
)
\AM@pagewidth=\dimen115
\AM@pageheight=\dimen116

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppluatex.def
File: ppluatex.def 2015/05/11 v0.4x Pdfpages driver for luaTeX (AM)
)
\AM@pagebox=\box26
\AM@toc@title=\toks16
\c@AM@survey=\count96
\AM@templatesizebox=\box27
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
Package: microtype 2013/05/23 v2.5a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
\MT@toks=\toks17
\MT@count=\count97
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 766.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen117
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textmicrotypecontext on input line 1285.
\MT@listname@count=\count98

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-luatex.def
File: microtype-luatex.def 2013/05/23 v2.5a Definitions specific to luatex (RS)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
Package: luatexbase 2013/05/11 v0.6 Resource management for the LuaTeX macro pro
grammer

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex.sty
Package: luatex 2010/03/09 v0.4 LuaTeX basic definition package (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
Package: etex 2015/03/02 v2.1 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
\et@xins=\count99
)
\LuT@AllocAttribute=\count277
\LuT@AllocCatcodeTable=\count278
\CatcodeTableStack=\count279
\CatcodeTableIniTeX=\catcodetable1
\CatcodeTableString=\catcodetable3
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable5
\CatcodeTableLaTeX=\catcodetable7

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty
Package: luatex-loader 2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-compat.sty
Package: luatexbase-compat 2011/05/24 v0.4 Compatibility tools for LuaTeX
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-modutils.s
ty
Package: luatexbase-modutils 2013/05/11 v0.6 Module utilities for LuaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-loader.sty
Package: luatexbase-loader 2013/05/11 v0.6 Lua module loader for LuaTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.loader.lua)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua)
Lua module: luatexbase-modutils 2013/05/11 0.6 Module utilities for LuaTeX
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-regs.sty
Package: luatexbase-regs 2011/05/24 v0.4 Registers allocation for LuaTeX
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-attr.sty
Package: luatexbase-attr 2013/05/11 v0.6 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/attr.lua)
Lua module: luatexbase-attr 2013/05/11 0.6 Attributes allocation for LuaTeX
\lltxb@attr@unsetvalue=\count280
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-cctb.sty
Package: luatexbase-cctb 2013/05/11 v0.6 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/cctb.lua)
Lua module: luatexbase-cctb 2013/05/11 0.6 Catcodetable allocation for LuaTeX
\lltxb@catcodetable@alloc=\count281
\CatcodeTableStack=\count282
\CatcodeTableIniTeX=\luatexcatcodetable1
\CatcodeTableString=\luatexcatcodetable3
\CatcodeTableOther=\luatexcatcodetable5
\CatcodeTableLaTeX=\luatexcatcodetable7
\CatcodeTableLaTeXAtLetter=\luatexcatcodetable9
\CatcodeTableExpl=\luatexcatcodetable11
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-mcb.sty
Package: luatexbase-mcb 2013/05/11 v0.6 Callback management for LuaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/mcb.lua)
Lua module: luatexbase-mcb 2013/05/11 0.6 register several functions in a callba
ck
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.lua)
Lua module: microtype 2013/05/15 2.5 microtype module.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 644.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lslig on input line 644.
\MT@outer@space=\skip256
)
Package microtype Info: Loading configuration file microtype.cfg.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg
File: microtype.cfg 2013/05/23 v2.5a microtype main configuration file (RS)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen256
\lightrulewidth=\dimen257
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen258
\belowrulesep=\dimen259
\belowbottomsep=\dimen260
\aboverulesep=\dimen261
\abovetopsep=\dimen262
\cmidrulesep=\dimen263
\cmidrulekern=\dimen264
\defaultaddspace=\dimen265
\@cmidla=\count283
\@cmidlb=\count284
\@aboverulesep=\dimen266
\@belowrulesep=\dimen267
\@thisruleclass=\count285
\@lastruleclass=\count286
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen268
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty
\bigstrutjot=\dimen269
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip257
\LTright=\skip258
\LTpre=\skip259
\LTpost=\skip260
\LTchunksize=\count287
\LTcapwidth=\dimen270
\LT@head=\box256
\LT@firsthead=\box257
\LT@foot=\box258
\LT@lastfoot=\box259
\LT@cols=\count288
\LT@rows=\count289
\c@LT@tables=\count290
\c@LT@chunks=\count291
\LT@p@ftn=\toks18
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty
Package: cleveref 2013/12/28 v0.19 Intelligent cross-referencing
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.ldf
Language: frenchb 2015/04/10 v3.1e French support from the babel system

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2014/09/25 3.9l Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count292
\U@D=\dimen271

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua)
luatex-hyphen: using data file: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/generic/co
nfig/language.dat.lua))
\l@acadian = a dialect from \language\l@french 
\l@canadien = a dialect from \language\l@french 
\FBcolonskip=\skip261
\FBthinskip=\skip262
Package frenchb.ldf Info: No need for active punctuation characters
(frenchb.ldf)             with this version of LuaTeX!
(frenchb.ldf)             reported on input line 200.
\FB@interchartokenstateORI=\count293
\FBguillskip=\skip263
\FBguill@level=\count294
\FB@Mht=\dimen272
LaTeX Info: Redefining \degres on input line 740.
\std@mcc=\count295
\dec@mcc=\count296
\listindentFB=\skip264
\labelwidthFB=\skip265
\leftmarginFB=\skip266
\parindentFFN=\dimen273
luatex-hyphen: loading patterns and exceptions for: french (\language26)
luatex-hyphen: info: no hyphenation exceptions for this language))
\FB@addDPspace=\luatexattribute1
\FB@addGUILspace=\luatexattribute2

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2015/03/14 v2.4c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2015/03/01 v5547 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2015/03/01 v5547 L3 programming layer (code) 
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2015/02/28 v5542 L3 Bootstrap code
L3 Module: l3names 2015/02/24 v5535 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2014/11/27 v5472 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2015/03/01 v5545 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2015/02/21 v5529 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count297
\l_tmpa_int=\count298
\l_tmpb_int=\count299
\g_tmpa_int=\count300
\g_tmpb_int=\count301
L3 Module: l3quark 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count302
L3 Module: l3clist 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2014/09/15 v5422 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2015/02/26 v5537 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2014/08/24 v5369 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count303
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count304
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count305
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count306
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count307
L3 Module: l3skip 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen274
\c_max_dim=\dimen275
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen276
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen277
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen278
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen279
\c_zero_skip=\skip267
\c_max_skip=\skip268
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip269
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip270
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip271
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip272
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
L3 Module: l3keys 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count308
\l_keys_choice_int=\count309
L3 Module: l3fp 2014/08/22 v5336 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count310
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count311
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count312
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count313
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count314
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count315
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count316
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count317
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count318
L3 Module: l3box 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box260
\l_tmpa_box=\box261
\l_tmpb_box=\box262
\g_tmpa_box=\box263
\g_tmpb_box=\box264
L3 Module: l3coffins 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box265
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen280
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen281
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen282
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen283
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen284
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen285
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen286
\c_empty_coffin=\box266
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box267
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box268
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box269
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box270
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box271
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box272
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box273
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen287
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen288
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen289
L3 Module: l3color 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3candidates 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen290
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen291
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen292
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen293
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen294
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen295
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen296
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen297
\l__box_internal_box=\box274
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen298
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen299
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen300
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen301
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen302
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen303
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen304
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def
File: l3unicode-data.def 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Unicode data
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def
File: l3pdfmode.def 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count319
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count320
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count321
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count322
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count323
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count324
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty
Package: luaotfload 2014/08/10 v2.5-4 OpenType layout system

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua)
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2014/08/10 2.50003 OpenType layout system.
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Brice

Comment: Does it work with a standard font?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue when compiling your code under either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Aside: The `\label` instruction must come *after* the `\caption` instruction.

Comment: Works fine for me too.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried with the standard font, and its worked ! But I really like my "custom" font, is there any way to keep my font without loosing the accents ? I use TexMaker 4.5, and this is the beginning of my log file : "This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015)".